# Difference between vector with magnitude, angle and vector with x, y

Tags: vector, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

What's the difference between a vector described with magnitude and angle and one described by x and y?  Or are they the same, just expressed differently?

Comment: I've made a guess as to what your question is, based on your title, and modified the text.  If I've guessed wrong, please change it back, and add any additional details.

Comment: No problem, your guess was correct :)

Comment: FYI, for Google-ing purposes, these are called "Polar Coordinates" and "Cartesian Coordinates", respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bijection of the two representations and you can use this:

```
x = r*cos(alpha);
y = r*sin(alpha);
```

So the two representation effectively do the same. Still one is to be preferred over the other for certain tasks. For instance rotation is easier if vector is expressed using magnitude and angle. On the other hand dot product is easier to compute using coordinates x and y.